# Update text on button by hitting api -Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change the text on button.On button click it hit the api and gives result as "Active" or "Inactive" but for that i have to refresh it however i want it to get updated as i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Async task to perform network operation. Return result in doInBackground() method and override onPostExecute() method and set the response to your button.

```
public class myClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

      //perform network operation and return response
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res){
      myButton.setText(res);
    }
```

}